Running multiple Optuna trials on each GPU to fully utilize available VRAM
I have an Optuna script for hyperparameter tuning that runs on four GPUs using the following command:
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python 'optuna script.py' &
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python 'optuna script.py' &
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2 python 'optuna script.py' &
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3 python 'optuna script.py' &

Each GPU has 24 GB of VRAM, but currently, each GPU is running only one trial at a time (taking about 1GB VRAM each and negligible processing power), making the process very slow. I want to fully utilize the available VRAM by running multiple trials on each GPU simultaneously.
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
def objective(trial):
    # Defined my neural network architecture, data loaders, loss function, and optimizer here
    ...

def main():
    storage_url = "mysql://optuna_user:optuna_password@localhost/optuna_db"
    study_name = "distributed-relapse-prediction-full"
    study = optuna.create_study(study_name=study_name, direction="maximize", storage=storage_url, load_if_exists=True)
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Is there a way to modify the script and/or the command to run multiple copies of the trials on each GPU, ensuring that all available VRAM is utilized efficiently? I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this.
Thank you in advance!

I am an idiot. This easily does what I want:
for i in {1..6}; do
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python 'optuna script.py' &
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python 'optuna script.py' &
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2 python 'optuna script.py' &
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3 python 'optuna script.py' &
done
Just run the scripts multiple times.

You want the create_study call to be done outside of these optimization process. Instead, set that up beforehand.
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS example"
optuna create-study --study-name "distributed-example" --storage "mysql://root@localhost/example"


then in the optimization codeimport optuna
def objective(trial):
    x = trial.suggest_float("x", -10, 10)
    return (x - 2) ** 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    study = optuna.load_study(
        study_name="distributed-example", storage="mysql://root@localhost/example"
    )
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100) 

